# How to put these two statements together

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'm trying to create a login form using combobox and two textboxes for username and password. In combobox, there are items Student and Teacher. I have created a sql database with two tables, one for student and another one for teacher. 
The following queries created:
Parameter name: StudentUserNameAndPassword

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS Result, UserName AS UserNameInput, Password AS       PasswordInput
    FROM     Student
    GROUP BY UserName, Password
    HAVING (COUNT(*) = 1) AND (UserName = @Param3) AND (Password = @Param4)
```

Parameter name: TeacherUserNameAndPassword

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS Result, UserName AS UserNameInput, Password AS PasswordInput
    FROM     Teacher[enter image description here][1]
    GROUP BY UserName, Password
    HAVING (COUNT(*) = 1) AND (UserName = @Param5) AND (Password = @Param6)
```

I have the following two statements code, which refer to correct username and password. But each one also return message of another one which is " Invalid Username or Password". How to put these statements together?

```
  Dim a = StudentTableAdapter.StudentUserNameAndPassword(Me.txtUserName.Text, Me.txtPassword.Text)
        Dim b = TeacherTableAdapter.TeacherUserNameAndPassword(Me.txtUserName.Text, Me.txtPassword.Text)
        txtUserName.Text = String.Empty
        txtPassword.Text = String.Empty
If a Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password")
        ElseIf cmbTeacherOrStudent.SelectedItem = ("Student") Then
            StudentForm.ShowDialog()
        End If

        If b Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password")
        ElseIf cmbTeacherOrStudent.SelectedItem = ("Teacher") Then
            TeacherForm.ShowDialog()
        End If
```

Comment: Do you have other statements to execute after, or can you simply return? If a is Nothing and b is Nothing, is there any other processing to do within this method?

Comment: No other statements to execute after.

Comment: Do you really need two separate `TableAdapter`? Are you querying two different databases based on if the current user is a teacher or a student? I think you need to review your design.

Comment: @Luc , Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UserName, 'S' as UserType     FROM     Student WHERE (UserName = @UserName) AND (Password = @Password)
UNION ALL
SELECT UserName, 'T' as UserType     FROM     Teacher WHERE (UserName = @UserName) AND (Password = @Password)
```

A UNION ALL will read from two tables, returning the results from both merged together into one list.

Comment: Thank you!
With this, user student can login with teacher username and password, and the same teacher can login with student username and password.

Comment: Really, you should have one `Person` table with both students and teachers. That way you can be sure that each username is only used one. Include a `PersonType` column with S or T.

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
If StudentTableAdapter.StudentUserNameAndPassword(Me.txtUserName.Text, Me.txtPassword.Text) And cmbTeacherOrStudent.SelectedItem = ("Student") Then
            StudentForm.ShowDialog()
        ElseIf TeacherTableAdapter.TeacherUserNameAndPassword(Me.txtUserName.Text, Me.txtPassword.Text) And cmbTeacherOrStudent.SelectedItem = ("Teacher") Then
            TeacherForm.ShowDialog()
        Else
            MsgBox("Wrong user type, username or password!")
        End If
```